# Eclipse Java - Program works in eclipse but not as runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

I am trying to export my program as a runnable jar. The program works absolutely fine inside of eclipse but it does not work as a runnable jar. I am using 3 other jar files as referenced jars so I can use audio, and I think this might be the problem. The runnable jar launches but its just an all white window and the program doesn't start.

I am clicking on my project and then right clicking and selecting "Export", then I am selecting the "runnable jar" option. I have tried creating the jar using all three of the options dealing with referenced libraries.

- Extract required libraries into generated jar
- Package required libraries into generated jar
- Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated jar

None of these options result in a working program. Hopefully you guys can help me!

---

**Edit**
yes there is an error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread 2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! 
  at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read 
  at main.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage<BufferedImageLoader.java:36>|
  at main.LoadScreen.<init><LoadScreen.java:38> at main.Engine.run<Engine.java:248> 
  at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: can you please post the error that you're facing?

Comment: It is not an error. The program just is a blank white screen and it doesn't actually start. but no errors in the code or upon launching the jar.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried running the jar from the command line to see if any error messages occur?

Comment: Oh I am sorry yes there is an error: Exception in thread "Thread 2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read
at main.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage<BufferedImageLoader.java:36>|at main.LoadScreen.<init><LoadScreen.java:38>
at main.Engine.run<Engine.java:248>
at java.lang.Thread.run

Comment: So it seems that the problem is it cannot find my images. but The program runs fine in eclipse so the images are there i just don't know how to pack them in the jar properly

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the images as files when you need to get them as resources. This is a common problem, one that generates a lot of similar questions on this site. Get your class loader or class and use it to `getResource(...)` to get your images.

i.e,

```
  BufferedImage westImg = ImageIO.read(getClass()
        .getResource("/images/img01.jpg"));
```

Comment: I think I am doing that though:

public BufferedImage loadImage(String path)
 {
  try {
   image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return image;
 }

Comment: @Smartypants: then are your images present in the jar file?

Comment: @Smartypants: what did you change?

Comment: I really bits when someone figures out their mistakes and then doesn't share it with others...